# HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH - Between different columns

Tags: sql, json, hive, amazon-athena

While querying the table I'm getting partition mismatch between different columns. Please note, mismatch is reported against different columns!

The error I'm getting is,

> HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table
> and partition schemas. The types are incompatible and cannot be
> coerced. The column '*direction*' in table 'heat.backup' is declared as
> type 'string', but partition
> 'partition_0=2020/partition_1=08/partition_2=07/partition_3=13'
> declared column '*scan_enabled*' as type 'boolean'.

As you can see, the error is raised against entirely different columns, 'direction' and 'scan_enabled'.  I have seen same error saying data type in table metadata is one type, but data type in partition's metadata is different for the ***SAME*** column, which makes sense. But in this case, data type of one column is compared against the data type of entirely different column.

The query is run against AWS Athena table, where the underlying data is JSON.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because of not the same column is of different type in both table and partition's metadata. It is because the schema of reported partition is not same as the table schema.

To confirm the same issue two boto3/(your choice of SDK) API calls [get_table](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_table)() and [get_partition](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_partition)(). This will tell you the difference between these two.

Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/updates-and-partitions.html) talks about the same issue which has different schema in partition when compared to Table schema.

As mentioned in the doc the work around for this issue is is to drop the partition that is causing the error and recreate it.If you are using Glue crawler then you need to enable "[Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html)" in your crawler settings.